# Calling a specific method in my Web API controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-resource

So I'm trying to make a call to this specific method:

```
[HttpGet]
public int GetLogin(string u, string p)
{
    UserLogin uL = new UserLogin();
    return (int)uL.Authenticate(u, p);
}
```

However it keeps calling this method in my Controller instead:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

^^ Which is the generated code in the Controller.

Here Angular code for my factory and, more importantly, my URI:

```
var loginFactory = angular.module('loginService', ['ngResource'])

loginFactory.factory('UserLogin', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/login?:username?:password', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: { username: 'hunter', password: 'hunter' },
            isArray:true
        }
    });
});
```

Any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your resource to this:

```
$resource('api/GetLogin?u=:username&p=:password', {}, {  // if that's the right route
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: { username: 'hunter', password: 'hunter' },
        isArray:true
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you have any links to a resource that teaches this syntax??

Answer (score 0):

Is your request going like `api/login?username=something&password=something`...?
if yes, the parameter names on the action should match the query string parameter names:

`public int GetLogin(string **username**, string **password**)`

Comment: Are you saying that my parameter names in my GetLogin(string username, string password)? And that those parameter names need to match my params: names in my factory?